# How do I modify and forward a variable number of arguments in a shell script

Tags: command-line

I want a script that I run thusly:

```
logphone Foo Bar Tar:I Baz:D
```

Which actually runs

```
adb -d logcat dalvikvm:I ActivityManager:W AndroidRuntime:W Foo:* Bar:* Tar:I Baz:D *:S
```

How do I do this with any number of parameters? Note that the order somewhat matters (Foo, Bar, etc. can't be at the end). Bash if it matters.

I can break the steps down to

1. For any number of command line arguments...
2. Check each argument for a colon (`:`)
3. If there's no colon add `:*`, otherwise leave it alone
4. Inject it into the command line `adb logcat dal…time:W __INJECTED_ARGS__ *:S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following bash code. Don't forget the shebang (if not /bin/bash) and `chmod +x script.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg; do
    if [[ "$arg" == *:* ]]; then
        args="$args $arg "
    else
        args="$args $arg:* "
    fi
done

exec adb -d logcat dalvikvm:I ActivityManager:W AndroidRuntime:W ${args[@]} *:S
```

If you have a recent bash (see it with `bash -version`), I can improve it a bit.

Comment: @sputnick, I made some improvements, before fully realizing what you might have meant by checking for bash version. Perhaps, you already had the solution using arrays in mind, but wasn't sure if Hounshell's bash supported it?